# Scope property visibility

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First of all, let me begin by saying that I'm new to AngularJS, so my code is probably full of anti-patterns. If that's the case, please let me know.

I'm using `angular-schema-form` and `angular-translate` to translate my labels. I have verified that the promise returned by the `$translate` service is resolved correctly, but for some reason the `$scope.labels` property is not visible outside of the promise.

I know this is probably a misunderstanding on my part of the inner workings of Angular, but I can't exactly grasp what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Here's the controller:

```
app = angular.module('myApp')

app.controller('SessionsController', ['$scope', '$translate',
  ($scope, $translate)->
    $scope.labels = []

    $translate(['models.user.labels.email', 'models.user.labels.password']).then(
      (translations)->
        $scope.labels = translations
    )

    # $scope.labels not visible here!

    $scope.loginFormSchema = {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        email: {
          type: 'string',
          title: $scope.labels['models.user.labels.email']
        },

        password: {
          type: 'string',
          title: $scope.labels['models.user.labels.password'],
          'x-schema-form': {
            type: 'password'
          }
        }
      },
      required: ['email', 'password']
    }

    $scope.loginForm = [
      '*',
      {
        type: 'submit',
        title: 'Sign in',
        style: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary'
      }
    ]

    $scope.login = {}
])
```

Comment: it's not visible as `$translate` returns a promise which will be resolved in next tick (it's async).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$translate` is async. You can do something like this:

```
app = angular.module('myApp')

app.controller('SessionsController', ['$scope', '$translate',
  ($scope, $translate)->
    $scope.loginFormSchema = {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        email: {
          type: 'string'
        },

        password: {
          type: 'string',
          'x-schema-form': {
            type: 'password'
          }
        }
      },
      required: ['email', 'password']
    }

    $scope.loginForm = [
      '*',
      {
        type: 'submit',
        title: 'Sign in',
        style: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary'
      }
    ]

    $scope.login = {}

    $translate(['models.user.labels.email', 'models.user.labels.password']).then(
      (translations)->
        //$scope.labels = translations
        $scope.loginFormSchema.properties.email.title = translations['models.user.labels.email'];
        $scope.loginFormSchema.properties.password.title = translations['models.user.labels.password'];
    )
])
```

Comment: It didn't occur to me that I could set the properties directly on the schema! Thanks a lot! :)